# Clear onComplete functions list in Promise

Tags: scala, promise, future

This snippet

```
val some = Promise[Int]()
some.success(20)
val someFuture = some.future
someFuture.onSuccess {case i => println(i)}
someFuture.onComplete {case iTry => List(println(iTry.get*2), println(iTry.get*3))}
```

creates promise with list of 3 callbacks(`List[CallbackRunnable]`) on complete. Is there a way to clear this List or rewrite it?

Comment: Don't think so. Unless maybe the callback is in a different `ExecutionContext` that you can kill separately.

Comment: Not really, - you can always make the future mutable and re-assign on it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I don't think re-assigning will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of technically possible. But definitely not in the way that you want. If we execute a `Future` (or `Promise`) in one `ExecutionContext`, and the callback in another, we can kill the callback's `ExecutionContext` so that it can't complete. This works in the REPL (throws an exception somewhere), but is terrible idea to actually try in real code:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import java.util.concurrent.Executors    

val ex1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
val ex2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
val ec1 = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(ex1)
val ec2 = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(ex2)

val f = Future { Thread.sleep(30000); println("done") }(ec1) // start in one ExecutionContext

f.onComplete { case t => println("onComplete done") }(ec2) // start callback in another ExecutionContext

ec2.shutdownNow

f.onComplete { case t => println("onComplete change") }(ec1) // start another callback in the original ExecutionContext
```

The first `onComplete` will not run (an exception is thrown in the background, which may or may not cause horrible things to happen elsewhere), but the second one does. But this is truly terrible, so don't do it.

Even if there was a construct to clear callbacks, it wouldn't be a good idea to use it.

```
someFuture.onComplete { case result => // do something important }

someFuture.clearCallbacks() // imaginary method to clear the callbacks

someFuture.onComplete { case result =>> // do something else }
```

The execution of this hypothetical code is non-deterministic. `someFuture` could complete before `clearCallbacks` is called, meaning *both* callbacks would get called, instead of just the second. But if it hasn't run yet, then only one callback will fire. There wouldn't be a nice way of determining that, which would lead to some truly horrible bugs.